# Change input text color

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple forms in html. The background is black so I want the typing text in white.

Here is what I have so far:

```html
<form method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name"><br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[image: picture of html website]
I highlight the typing text in the picture "asdasd" I want the user can type their text in color white. I've tried `color: #ffffff;` in CSS, but it does not works.

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Obviously you have **not** tried `color: #ffffff;`, otherwise you wouldn't have this problem. In any case, why don't you show the CSS code you tried, including the selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to fix this by doing this:

```html
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" style="color:white;">
```

For a neater look, you could also do this:

```html
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
```

```css
input {
  color:white;
}
```

Or, if you only want to apply the white text to one input, you could do this:

```html
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" id="input1">
```

```css
#input1 {
  color:white;
}
```

If you want to make the placeholder the same color, or a similar color, use the solution by @Çağrı.

Answer (score 1):

In css u should change both color of input and placeholder of input to white.

```
input[type=text],input[type=text]::placeholder{
 color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Try something like this?`

```
input[type=text] {
  background-color: #3CBC8D;
  color: white;
}
```